# Android In-App billing subscriptions test not working

Tags: android, testing, in-app-billing

I'm trying to test In-App billing subscriptions. My personal account and my developer account are the same. I can't buy my own products with this account, so, I need to test with another account. Here are the steps I followed:

- created a new account (lets call it account B)
- added account B on Google Play on my phone
- uploaded a signed apk for beta test
- created a beta testers list and added account B
- connected to account B on my phone in Firefox, went to the test link, opted-in, and installed the app (from Firefox, not from Play Store)
- bought an item
- been charged (and auto-refunded myself -_- ...)

So, seems like its not exactly working. After reading again the [developer guide](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html), I saw that when an account is set as a tester account, it is clearly stated in the in-app billing popup that you will not been charged:

> However, Google Play marks test purchases with a notice across the center of the purchase dialog, for easy identification

There is nothing like this in my popups. Does anyone know where can be the mistake?

I saw on some questions on stackoverflow that it might not be possible to have a phone set up for testing if the testing account is not the primary account on Google Play app, is that true?

EDIT: I added a friend's account to the list and asked him to test. He has only one account on his phone. Like me, nothing indicates that he would not be charged (and so, I guess that, like me, he would).

EDIT: I see this in the guide:

> Note: For test subscription purchases, leave the orderId field blank. You can use the purchaseToken field to identify test purchases.

What does they mean by "For test subscription purchases, leave the orderId field blank"? Do I need to do something here, or does they mean that in the response, the field is left blank?

Answer (score 3):

> However, Google Play marks test purchases with a notice across the
>   center of the purchase dialog, for easy identification

The purchase dialog should display a message as shown in the image below:

[image]

> Note: For test subscription purchases, leave the orderId field blank.
>   You can use the purchaseToken field to identify test purchases.

It means orderId field for test purchases is blank in the response. This is because a real order wasn't placed and so no order id is created for the test purchase.

**Update**
For test purchase, create license test accounts for authorized users. In the Developer Console, go to Settings > Account details, then in the License Testing section, add the addresses to Gmail accounts with testing access field.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I suspected. Thanks also for the screen, mine is not like this :/ . Did you do something special to have test purchases? My testers can download the app through the link provided on the developers console (the app is not released yet), so the test is at least partially working.

Comment: I create license test accounts for authorized users. In the Developer Console, go to Settings > Account details, then in the License Testing section, add the addresses to Gmail accounts with testing access field.

Comment: Thanks, it works!! Please update your answer with your last comment and I'll accept it. I only added the accounts in the app page, not in my global account setting.